# CGridview With Custom Dataprovider That Doesn't Load All Records From Source (Lazy Loading)

Tags: yii, lazy-loading

I'm a 5-day Yii fan trying to learn the ropes of this great framework. I would really appreciate it if you could bear with me reading through my problem and help me out.

So here goes, I'm retrieving a list of products sold by a particular merchant of an online marketplace through its web service. When I query the web service like this

```
api.marketplace.com?merchant_id=1234
```

I'll get back the response in JSON which consists of two main pieces of data

1. The number of products sold by Merchant 1234 (**total_products**)
2. The list (array) of the products sold (**list_product**). Each element in this array represents one distinct Product object with two fields: **product_id** and **product_name** respectively.

So if **total_products = 934**, there'll be 934 elements in the array.
When I put it in codes, my derived DataProvider looks like this

```
class ProductDataProvider extends CDataProvider /* or should I extend other better class? */ {
    public function __construct($config = array()) {
    foreach($config as $key=>$value)
        $this->$key=$value;
    }    

    protected function fetchData() {
        $request = "api.marketplace.com?merchant_id=1234";
        $response = retrieveProductsAndProcessJSONResponseIntoAppropriateDataStructure($request);
        $this->setTotalItemCount($response->total_products);

        if(($pagination=$this->getPagination())!==false)
            $pagination->setItemCount($this->getTotalItemCount());

        return $response->list_products;
    }

    protected function calculateTotalItemCount() {
        return $this->getTotalItemCount();
    }
}
```

My model

```
class Product extends CModel {
    public $product_id;
    public $product_name;

    public function display() {
        return new ProductDataProvider(array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
        ));
    }
}
```

and my View

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'product-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->display(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'product_id',
        'product_name',
    ),
));
```

This works well with pagination and all that. However retrieving all 934 products is taking a bit too long. We can do this to the web service.

```
api.marketplace.com?merchant_id=1234&page_size=10&page_no=1
```

This will only retrieve the first 10 records. We can play around with the query string variable **page_no** to retrieve subsequent pages of products in groups of 10. The **total_products** returned from the web service will still be 934.

So my question is, how do I put this into play so that the `ProductDataProvider` only retrieves 10 product at any one time and load it into CGridView? The CGridView will have to know that there are a total of 934 products to enable pagination. User browsing to other pages of the CGridView will trigger the ProductDataProvider to retrieve the next 10 records corresponding to the page number being viewed. I hope that my long winded question is comprehensible.

Comment: Look into the pagination system of dataproviders. It's generally aimed at SQL pagination, but with a custom pagination class, you should be able to handle things as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. So, I think:

Firstly, you should implement all 3 abstract methods from `CDataProvider`. In your class `fetchKeys()` is not implemented.

Secondly, pagination logic should be put in `fetchData`. For instance:

```
protected function fetchData() {
    $request = "api.marketplace.com?merchant_id=1234";
    // page size
    $request .= "&page_size=".$this->pagination->pageSize;
    // current page
    $request .= "&page_no=".$this->pagination->currentPage;
    $response = retrieveProductsAndProcessJSONResponseIntoAppropriateDataStructure($request);

    return $response->list_products;
}
```

To use your new custom data provider write smth like that:

```
$dataProvider = new CustomDataProvider();
$pages = new CPagination($dataProvider->getTotalItemCount());
$pages->pageSize = 40; // page size
$dataProvider->pagination = $pages;
```

Data providers get total number of items using `calculateTotalItemCount()`. So, in addition, you should write there some logic to provide total item count. Guess, you should exploit another method in your API for that purpose. Remember, that if you use pagination, your data provider will do 2 api requests: the first for total item count and the second for current page items. Some can say that only one request is enough, but in this case, that request will return all data (934 elements). So heavy.

That's all you need.

Comment: I got it working a little while ago before I saw this, my approach is basically the same except that instead of `$this->pagination->pageSize`, i used `$this->getPagination()->getLimit()` and instead of `$this->pagination->currentPage`, i used `$this->getPagination()->getOffset()`.

It's the same thing anyway. Yii offers more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to create your own custom data provider.  See the Class Reference for [CDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider)

There are three implemented data providers in Yii.  CActiveDataProvider, CArrayDataProvider, and CSqlDataProvider.  You can use those as a model for your custom data provider.

Comment: I did. If you read my codes, I've created my custom DataProvider `ProductDataProvider`. But that'll just grab everything from the web service. I need to know how can I implement lazy-loading without retrieving all records but still gives the ability to the CGridView to browse other "unloaded" records which will be retrieved on the fly